# the error "invalid literal for int() with base 10:" keeps coming up

Tags: python, string, syntax, int

I'm trying to write a very simple program, I want to print out the sum of all the multiples of 3 and 5 below 100, but, an error keeps accuring, saying "invalid literal for int() with base 10:" my program is as follows:

```
sum = ""
sum_int = int(sum)
for i in range(1, 101):
    if i % 5 == 0:
        sum += i 
    elif i % 3 == 0:
        sum += i
    else:
        sum += ""

print sum
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to append a string ("") to a number?

Comment: this has absolute no sense: `int('')`. `sum(i for i in range(1, 101) if (i % 3 == 0) or (i % 5 == 0))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `""` are the cause of these problems.

Change

```
sum = ""
```

to

```
sum = 0
```

and get rid of

```
else:
 sum += ""
```

Answer (score 7):

Python is not JavaScript: `""` does not automatically convert to `0`, and `0` does not automatically convert to `"0"`.

Your program also seems to be confused between printing the sum of all the multiples of three and five and printing a list of all the numbers which are multiples of three and five.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I'm new to Python so I was doing quite a few silly things; anyway, I think I've worked it out now.

```
sum = 0
for i in range(1, 1001):
    if i % 5 == 0:
        sum += i 
    elif i % 3 == 0:
        sum += i

print sum
```